# How to add new index row in Pandas Data Frame based on values in other rows in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas as below:

```
IDX  | ALL | COL1 | COL2
------------------------
ABC  | 100 | 50   | 214
DEF  | 250 | 32   | 89
GHI  | 120 | 18   | 12
```

"IDX" is an index column.
I would like to add new row in this Data Frame which will calculate mathematic formula like:

```
(value from index DEF - value from index GHI) and result / by value from index DEF
```

So for example: (250 - 120) / 250 = 0.52
So as a result I need something like below:

```
IDX  | ALL | COL1 | COL2
------------------------
ABC  | 100 | 50   | 214
DEF  | 250 | 32   | 89
GHI  | 120 | 18   | 12
new1 | 0.52| 0.44 | 0.87
```

because:

- (250 - 120) / 250 = 0.52
- (32 - 18) / 32 = 0.44
- (89 - 12) / 89 = 0.87

How can I do that in Python Pandas ? Be aware that IDX is an index column

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select and set by indices:

```
#if need IDX convert to df.index
df = df.set_index('IDX')

df.loc['new1'] = df.loc['DEF'].sub(df.loc['GHI']).div(df.loc['DEF'])
```

Comment: Is it also works if for example column IDX is not index but normal column ?

Comment: @Matop - Use `df = df.set_index('IDX')` - convert `IDX` to index

Comment: Ok, and last question, because If i use your code all my DataFrame convert to science notification, but if I try to drop sceicne notification from DR by: pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format in our new row "new1" I have 0 what can I do ?

Comment: @Matop - Not sure if understand, need `0.0000` ?  Because `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}` only change displaying values, values are in DataFrame not changed.

Comment: My problem is: I have int64 values in DF, then I use your code and values in my DF changed to float for example 145.00000, and in terms of our new index "new1" it is ok, but rest of values in other indexes i would like to have still as int64, so for example 124 not 124.00000 how can I do that ?

Comment: @Matop - It is problem, because each column has same type. If need different, need transpose `df = df.set_index('IDX').T` and then `df['new1'] = df['DEF'].sub(df['GHI']).div(df['DEF'])`